# Check if the result of the query belongs to one instance

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following query:

```
Promise.join<any>(
    db.User.findAll({
      where: {
        email: {
          $like: '%'+req.query.q+'%'
    }}}),
    db.Investor.findAll({
      where: {
        $or: {
          firstName: { $like: req.query.q+'%' },
          lastName: { $like: req.query.q+'%' }
    }}}),
    (users, investors) => {
      if (!users && !investors) {
        throw new error.NotFoundError('No result match your search criteria!');
      } else {
        return (users ? users : investors);
      }
    }
  ).then((results) => {
   ...
```

how can I know if results is an array of users or investors? does it exist a fast way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe instance.constructor.name should contain what you are looking for. It's also possible to do

```
Instance instanceof db.User
```

But you would have to validate each entry in the array. You could use .map to filter out any results that are not one of the two

```
results.map( function(result) { return result instanceof db.User || result instanceof db.Investors} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change return statement as below.

```
return ( users ? { "users": users } : { "investors": investors } );
```

And parse the returning map to get either `"users"` or `"investors"` objects.